# Blacklist the linux tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-block-request

I don't see any use for the [linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag.

It would seem to me that the only valid uses are when it is used instead of the [kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel) tag.

Comment: Completely agree. Linux is just another term for the kernel, and the latter is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the list of questions, I think some of the questions need to be cleaned up first. It is not clear to me what this tag is actually used for based on browsing 15-30 questions with it.

Comment: That's exactly my point - the tag isn't being used for anything, just being randomly added to questions by users.

Comment: @flute ok I destroyed this tag, you now have 3 questions tagged [untagged]

Comment: It looks like the tag came back, right now there are two questions with it (one of them closed, though).

Comment: This tag is once again building up cruft, I went ahead and cleaned it up if you want to destroy it again.

Comment: @jorge ok, I am adding `^linux|unix$` as intrinsic blacklisted tags then