# Ayatana, linux and tips tags becoming too meta?

Tags: support, tags

As we add things under the umbrella [ayatana](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ayatana) project it's becoming too meta and doesn't really mean anything anymore.

- [tips](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tips) also appears to be not useful.
- [linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/linux) isn't being used for the kernel, but more as a "I happen to be running linux" tag. This was once [cleaned up](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/985/blacklist-the-linux-tag) but it appears to be back, perhaps just symlink it to [kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel)?

I've checked the affected questions and they all have proper tags to the subprojects, which is better anyway, so safe to remove those tags.

Comment: I originally read this as "Ayatana tag becoming too metal?"

Answer (score 10):

What Jorge says makes sense.

No need for every [unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity) (1298) and [indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/indicator) (203) to also be tagged [ayatana](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ayatana) (22).

I can think of no situations where it would be particularly useful.

Answer (score 1):

For clearness, what about renaming [linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/linux) to [linux-kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel)? That tag will be suggested when users tag questions and will avoid the use of [linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/linux). [kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel) does not necessarily have to do with Linux, but even the tag description says so. Perhaps all of the questions tagged [kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel) should be moved to [linux-kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel) for the above mentioned reason.

Comment: I don't see why we need the "linux" there, I don't think people will mix it up with the hurd or whatever.

Comment: @JorgeCastro: I agree, but with both of you. It is unfortunate, but many inexperienced users will think Linux == Kernel == Linux. They don't really stop to pick up on the specifics, so it is useful to have [tag:linux-kernel] tag IMHO.