# Fix the Linux tag blacklist

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-block-request

A million years ago (in Internet years), [Jeff](http://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=accounts) put a [tag blacklist in place](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/985/blacklist-the-linux-tag#comment2478_987) to stop people tagging things with `linux` or `unix`. Probably makes sense but I think his regex was bum:

```
^linux|unix$
```

That's [being interpreted as](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Elinux%7Cunix%24&i=linux-headers%0D%0Alinux%0D%0Anot-linux%0D%0Aunix-sucks%0D%0A&o=im):

> begins with `linux` *or* ends with `unix`

I don't think this was the original aim here.

Why is this a problem? Well I've just tried to tag something as `linux-headers` (a real package in Ubuntu) and a pretty important one if you're compiling stuff against the kernel. Of course there are flowery alternative I could pick (or create), but I just don't see why this is blocked.

TL;DR: I think we need the regex updating to:

```
^(linux|unix)$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed and active. Ping me if there are problems down the line.

Comment: Thanks. That works now.